# How to choose a good start point for a least square fitting problem, if the result is highly depended on a good initial guess

Tags: optimization, least-squares

A two-dimensional pattern have five parameters. I hope to perform a least square fitting of this pattern to solve for the unknown parameters.

The problem is, whether we could find a good result is highly depend on the initial guess. The only thing I can think of is to just randomly choose initial guess, then I pick the one with the least square error as the result? 
Any better strategies for choosing the initial guess?

Comment: Are you talking about regression? If so, there is a lot of software than will run least-squares regression on whatever data you want - you definitely do not need to do this by hand or write your own software.

Comment: You could make a set of initial guesses, then let the performance of each solution decide how much they affect the starting points for a new set of guesses, so you iterate your way forward. This has the benefit of being parallellizable as each least squares solution should take about the same amount of computations.

Comment: @ ZubinMukerjee I know there is a lot of software, but even so I still need to assign a good initial guess(close to the ground truth) to get a good result. I hope to know is there any better strategy for such case.

Comment: If you can measure how crappy the solution is, you can apply the same strategies as in general non-linear optimization, minimizing the error. Line search methods, trust-region methods et.c.

Comment: @mathreadler I think maybe the problems is I always got caught by local minimum, and randomly choose initial guess could help me get closer to a global minimum. and the problem turns into, what kind of strategy could help me get close to a global minimum.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: your "full confidence" on software power is .. naive.

Comment: all (let's say much) depends on the relation between the parameters and the point coordinates/curve shape, and on how much each parameter interfere with the others. If these are "intricated" (non-linear) you cannot do much different than to rely on the knowledge of physical underlying system, to guess initial value /admissible range for the parameters.

Comment: @GCab Yes, I had incorrectly assumed that this was linear least-squares.

Comment: [This section of the Wikipedia article on non-linear least squares states without reference that it is good to use "computer simulation" to find initial parameter estimates...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares#Initial_parameter_estimates) incredibly vague

Comment: @GCab let's say, after I narrow the range of the unknown parameters. Is there any better strategy than randomly choose a guess in that range.

Comment: I have some experience with data interpolation and can assure to you that in your case (5 parameters, thus a bit complicated, without knowing the details) math is just a tool that is up to you to manoevre. After you fix the range, what is the probability distribution of the parameters inside it (uniform, gaussian,..), depend on the system that generated the values and /or instruments that measured them: in hypothesizing these math cannot tell you anything.